# Vue JS custom component v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hello everyone i have a bit of a problem trying to get `v-model` to work on a custom component i've created. The problem is that this component consists of two **inputs**, and each time these are changed i emit the `"input"` event and bind it to an array i have on the parent.

```
<key-value-input v-for="n in inputs" v-model="provider.params"></key-value-input>
```

Then in the Component itself...

```
        updateData() {
            this.$emit('input', {
                key: this.inputData.key,
                value: this.inputData.value
            })
        }
```

This kinda works the problem is that it replaces `provider.params` from the **original empty array** into an **object** containing only one of the several key-value combinations i might have since this component can be duplicated at runtime...

So the question is, how do i make it so that v-model can fetch the data from each sub-component and simply set it as objects in an array on the parent?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply use `v-model` on the array element itself:

```
<key-value-input v-for="n in inputs" v-model="provider.params[n-1]"></key-value-input>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2be4maxm/

Comment: `:value` would be more appropriate than `v-model="inputData.key"` in your component template, since you have a separate handler to issue the emits. [This updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2be4maxm/1/) shows how you could use `v-model`.

Comment: @RoyJ Ah yes of course, it was just a quick mock up based on the description, pieced together in a bit of an ad-hoc manner, but yes, `:value` would be better. ;)